# Pandas read_excel numbering Same Column Names in Excel even if its not repeated in UseCols range

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel Sheet Similar to below example

in excel from A to E

| Object Name | Col Name |  | Object Name | File name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KT | Category |  | KT | KTOut.csv |
| KT | SubCategory |  | KC | KCOut.csv |

```
df = pd.read_excel('map.xlsx', usecols='D:E')
```

In the df, Object column is coming as Object.1

Since iam not reading the A:B, why pandas is renaming. Can it be avoided? or is there a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround could be to read the column headers directly, using openpyxl for example, and then rename the columns after `read_excel`:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('map.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
usecols='D:E'
cols = [col[0].value for col in ws[usecols]]

df = pd.read_excel('map.xlsx', usecols=usecols)
df.columns = cols
```